# PLAY_VIDEO menu item does not autoplay

Tags: google-mirror-api

i just implemented the PLAY_VIDEO menu item linked to a youtube video and it works.
The only enhancement i want to make to the flow is to remove one tap in order to stream the video.

Now the flow is the following:
1) User taps to prompt the menu for the card. The PLAY menu item appears.
2) The user taps on PLAY, the video start to load
3) The user needs to tap again to start the video.

Is there a way to stream the video right after the tap from point 2?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to setup a menu hierarchy, which I think is what you're getting at.

Plus, having that extra tap would be an inconsistent experience with the way playback behaves on Glass in the native app and other apps being created.

Why do you want to do the extra tap?